# @ejb injection works, jndi lookup doesn't in Glassfish 3

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I have a stateless ejb.

```
@Remote
public interface MyService {
   ...
}

impl

@Stateless
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  ...
}
```

I have another bean which is trying to use MyService, that will be exposed via JMX.

```
@MXBean
public interface MyJMXBean {
   ...
}

@Singleton
@Startup
public class MyJMXBeanImpl implements MyJMXBean {
   @EJB
   MyService service; // this works

   @PostConstruct
   private void init() { ... }

   @PreDestroy
   private void cleanup() { ... }

   // this doesn't
   private MyService doLookup() {
      InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
      return (MyService) ctx.lookup(MyService.class.getName());
   }
}
```

I would like to be able to do a jndi lookup of MyService so I don't have the deployment dependency on the ear that provides MyService.  The ears providing MyService and MyJMXBean are different, but deployed to the same container.  The exception I'm getting is:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:542) ~[glassfish-naming.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455) ~[glassfish-naming.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.java:71) ~[ejb-container.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:580) ~[glassfish-naming.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:514) ~[glassfish-naming.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl
        at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.create_impl(ORB.java:314) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:353) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.corba.CorbaUtils.getOrb(CorbaUtils.java:203) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.getDefaultOrb(CNCtx.java:72) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.initOrbAndRootContext(CNCtx.java:234) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.<init>(CNCtx.java:105) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory.getInitialContext(CNCtxFactory.java:49) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.IIOPObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(IIOPObjectFactory.java:73) ~[glassfish-naming.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:580) ~[glassfish-naming.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:514) ~[glassfish-naming.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.create_impl(ORB.java:312) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        ... 57 common frames omitted
```

I'm not quite sure how to resolve the ClassNotFoundException, as everything is running inside Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish V3 supports EJB  3.1 and implements the syntax for portable global session bean JNDI names in EJB 3.1 as below

```
java:global[/<app-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>
```

`<bean-name>` corresponds to the session bean's EJB name.  It defaults to the **unqualified** name of the session bean class.  It can be explicitly specified using the name attribute of the `@Stateless/@Stateful/@Singleton` annotation.

What you looked up in the JNDI tree was the qualified name of the EJB class.

You can check out the [GlassFish EJB FAQ](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#What_is_the_syntax_for_portable_global_) for details.

Comment: I used this form in the lookup string as well, and get the same exception.  The form I'm using currently works successfully elsewhere in the app as well as with a remote client.